# Удаление первой строки файла средствами PHP

Tags: php, строки, файлы

Есть файл например list.txt в котором несколько строк, например:

```
Строка1
Строка2
Строка3
```

Нужно на php выполнить такое:

```
$a = строка1;
Удалить первую строку;
Сохранить новый list.txt
```

Задача вроде простая, но постоянно что-то не получается. Спасибо за ответ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В самом простом случае (если размер файла не велик) решение может выглядеть следующим образом

```
<?php
  $lines = file('list.txt');
  unset($lines[0]);
  file_put_contents('list.txt', implode('', $lines));
```

Если файл объемный и записывать его полностью в память - не вариант, можно воссоздать рядом временный файл без первой строки и после того, как он успешно будет создан, переименовать его в list.txt

```
<?php
$fd = fopen('list.txt', 'r');
$tm = fopen($tmpname = tempnam('.', 'list'), 'w+');
if($fd === false) exit('Не могу открыть целевой файл');
if($tm === false) exit('Не могу открыть временный файл');
$i = 0;
while (($line = fgets($fd)) !== false) {
  if(++$i == 1) continue;
  fwrite($tm, $line);
}
fclose($fd);
fclose($tm);
rename($tmpname, 'list.txt');
```

Comment: Вот такой еще вопрос, если в файле 1000-2000 строчок по 7-9 символов, то как лучше сделать?

Comment: @AndrewBaliy Первый вариант выполняется полностью в оперативной памяти, второй на жестком диске. Поэтому первый вариант всегда быстрее второго. Размер памяти, отводимой скрипту определяется директивой memory_limit в php.ini, по умолчанию она 128Мб, если ваш файл заведомо меньше этой величины, можно смело пользоваться первым вариантом. Если файл пол гигабайта, вам придется либо пользоваться вторым вариантом, либо, если это единоразовая задача на вашей локальной машине снять ограничение на память скрипта.